# Пропала админ панель

Tags: wordpress

Пропала админ панель Wordpress, в чем может быть причина, вроде как никаких файлов не трогал... При этом в настройках галочка на отображение панели стоит[image]

Comment: Вы из аккаунта, случаем, не вышли?

Comment: не вышел, скажем так, если зайти с другого браузера, где я точно не авторизирован, там нету этой пустой полоски и сайт сразу начинается с черной полоски, а сейчас я авторизирован, но вместо панели отображается лишь место на котором должна быть панель.

Comment: Дайте URL сайта.

Comment: http://eddem.com.ua

Comment: А всё решается строчкой `<?php wp_body_open(); ?>` после `<body>`

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому, что остался отступ, причиной неполадки стала некорректная тема. [Здесь](http://techsolve.ru/esli-v-wordpress-propalo-verhnee-menyu-admin-panel.html) подробно рассказано о том, как исправить ошибку такого рода.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, но к сожалению все что рекомендовалось в данной статье у меня есть...

Comment: Поищите в html-файле страницы `<div id="wpadminbar" class="no-grav">`. Если есть - просто криво сделали тему.

Comment: Не нашел такой строчки...

Answer (score 1):

А вас не смущает, что сайт заканчивается началом артикля? Ни footera, ни закрывающего body, ни закрывающего html...

у вас в коде всего 164 строчки и почти все они отвечают только за шапку. Прежде чем искать этот бар, сначала полный каркас сайта выведите, а уже потом возможно и бар ваш покажется. Там явно фатальная ошибка в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, дело в том, что у вас в `header.php` нет вызова `wp_head();`

Comment: Есть, тем более в коде страницы есть код стилей: html { margin-top: 32px !important; } .....

Comment: Вот скриншот: http://piccy.info/view3/12218632/69fc1e9df8b1ba6fea4be283702f7f8c/orig/

Comment: Ага, я понял в чем дело, вы же считаетесь как не авторизованный пользователь, соответственно у вас нету админ панели и пустого места, для примера, в режиме инкогнито в исходном коде тоже нету данных строк, но в браузере, где я авторизирован как админ, админ панели нету, а есть пустая строка, соответственно я брал исходный код для админа...

Comment: А id=wpadminbar есть в html?

Comment: Ага, вот, нашел проблему, как ее можно исправить? http://piccy.info/view3/12218987/63816f1f64ad288cda4a103cd6e72f84/orig/

Comment: Это не проблема, он всегда так выводится функцией wp_admin_bar_header(). Смотрите текущие стили css в dev tools